# Functional programming RamdaJs arity question

Tags: ramda.js

I have a question for curity of the functions with Ramda and in FP as a whole.

In RamdaJs some of the functions accept 2,3 arguments, but some of them are curried (accept one or two parameters and return another functions).

For example:

```
const isBlackCard = R.anyPass([isClub, isSpade]);
isBlackCard({rank: '10', suit: '♣'}); //=> true
```

anyPass - returns another function that waits for the object.

```
R.reduce(R.add, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

In that case reduce waits for all the parameters and returns the result => 10

If I follow the previous example why reduce is not the same as anyPass, like this:

```
const adder = R.reduce(R.add, 0);
const sum = adder([1, 2, 3, 4]); //10
```

That way they will look identical.

So why they are not similar and is there any rule when to create one or the other.

If we chose the wrong way for a given function from the beginning it will be very hard to change in the future since it will be used in a lot of places.

Also some of the libraries use similar names with curried and uncurried but I dont like the idea because it is copy-like.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most Ramda functions are like `reduce` here.  They are curried in such a way that, for instance, `fn(a)(b)(c)`, `fn(a, b)(c)`, `fn(a)(b, c)` and `fn(a, b, c)` all return the same value.  A small set of Ramda functions are different.

Usually the reason for this is Ramda's handling of variadic functions (that is, those that take a varying number of arguments).  Ramda doesn't like exposing variadic functions.  (For historical reasons, `pipe` and `compose` and their kin are still variadic, but there aren't many others.)  But Ramda often works with variadic functions supplied by the user.  The functions supplied to `anyPass` or `allPass` don't have to be unary.  Here we pass binary functions to `anyPass`:

```js
const sameParity = (a, b) => a % 2 == b % 2

const foobar = R.anyPass ([gt, sameParity])

foobar (10, 8)  //=> true
foobar (10, 14) //=> true
foobar (5, 7)   //=> true
foobar (5, 14)  //=> false
foobar (5, 8)   //=> false
```

And we could pass ternary or even higher-arity functions.

But then how would we expect to pass parameters directly to such functions?  We could possibly write `anyPass([isSpade, isClub], {rank: 'K', suit: '♣'}).  But would we also write`anyPass([gt, sameParity], 10, 8)`?  If so, the input to`anyPass` becomes "an array of functions followed by an arbitrary number of other parameters" -- hardly a disciplined function.

Alternatively, we could restructure `anyPass` so that it takes an array of functions, followed by an array of parameters.  This sounds good until you realize how unergonomic that might be: Instead of `isBlackCard(myCard)`, you would have to call `isBlackCard([myCard])`.  That feels really wrong.

So, for these few functions, there is a compromise: they only return a function and never try to apply it to your values.

---

You ask this:

> If I follow the previous example why reduce is not the same as anyPass, like this:
>
> ```js
> const adder = R.reduce(R.add, 0);
> const sum = adder([1, 2, 3, 4]); //10
> ```

Well, in fact it is like that.  You can call `reduce`, like the majority of Ramda functions, with any initial subset of its parameters and get back a function waiting for the others.

```js
const adder = R.reduce(R.add, 0);
const sum = adder([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(sum)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

The only real difference is that you could *also* call it as `reduce(add, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4])`.

But if you want consistency, outside the few actual variadic functions in Ramda, you can call all of them in this style with no loss in functionality:

```js
reduce (add) (0) ([1, 2, 3, 4])
anyPass ([isClub, isSpade]) (myCard)
```

Passing the arguments one-by-one has actually become my preferred style these days.

Answer (score 0):

In ramda *every function is curried by default*:

> Ramda functions are automatically curried. This allows you to easily build up new functions from old ones simply by not supplying the final parameters.

You can look at the doc here: https://ramdajs.com/

This basically means that if a function has a arity of 3:

```
const foo = R.curry((a, b, c) => a + b + c);
```

a new function will be returned until all the 3 arguments are provided.

```
foo(1) // => foo(1, b, c)
foo(1, 2) => // foo(1, 2, c)
foo(1)(2)(3) // => 6
```

when all the arguments are finally passed:

```
foo(1, 2, 3) // => 6
```